# Probability that all extracted balls are different

Tags: probability

> In a pot there are $M$ balls numbered from $1$ to $M$. Extracting $n$ balls from the pot **with reimbursement** and recording the extracted ball **in order**, what's the probability $p$ that all extracted balls are different?

I was thinking in the following way:

- number of dispositions of $n$ different elements in $n$ positions is $P_n= n!$
- number of dispositions of $M$ elements which can be repeated in $n$ positions is $D^*_{M,n}=M^n$

So probability $p$ is $$p=\frac{P_n}{D^*_{M,n}}=\frac{n!}{M^n}$$

Could anyone tell me if I'm wrong?

Comment: You should consider the case where $n \ge M$

Comment: @Bram28 in that case, probability should be obviously $zero$.

Comment: Right, but your formula does not reflect this ... so something is wrong with your formula .. or you should say that the formula only works for $n < M$, and that $p=0$ for $n \ge M$

Comment: Yeah, maybe.. The text of exercise doesn't say anything about it, so I should simply say the formula works just for $n\leq M$, while we have $p=0$ if $n > M$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is wrong.  Take a simple example: $M=5$ and $n=3$

There are $5*4*3$ ways to get $3$ different balls, not $3!$

Do you see how to fix your formula?

(and also how the case where $n \ge M$ is handled?)

Comment: So is the number of dispositions of $M$ different elements in $n$ positions $D_{M,n}=\frac{M!}{(M-n)!}$?

And the probability $p$ will be $\frac{D_{M,n}}{D^*_{M,n}}$?

Comment: @ChuckTheYellow I am not sure how your $D_{M,n}$ is defined ... and $D^*_{M,n}$.  But in your enumerator you should get $M*(M-1)*(M-2)* ....*(M-n+1)$ ... note that that will actually automatically take care of the $n > M$ case as well, since with $n=M+1$ the $M-n+1$ term becomes $0$.

Comment: my enumerator is $D_{M,n}=\frac{M!}{(M-n)!}=(M-n+1)$. So we're saying the same thing.

Comment: @ChuckTheYellow Ah, ok, I never saw that notation. But yes, that's what you want, and like I said, that one will automatically take care of the $n > M$ cases.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much! I will delete this comment and the last but one comment. You should delete your last comment!